# Pandas Rank: unexpected behavior for method = 'dense' and pct = True

Tags: python, pandas, rank, dense-rank

Suppose I have a series with duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Series([1,2,3,4] * 5)
```

and I want to calculate percentile ranks of it. 
It is always a bit tricky to calculate ranks with multiple matches, but I think I am getting unexpected results:

```
ts.rank(method = 'dense', pct = True)

Out[112]: 
0     0.05
1     0.10
2     0.15
3     0.20
4     0.05
5     0.10
6     0.15
7     0.20
8     0.05
9     0.10
10    0.15
11    0.20
12    0.05
13    0.10
14    0.15
15    0.20
16    0.05
17    0.10
18    0.15
19    0.20
dtype: float64
```

So I am getting as percentiles [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2], where I guess the expected output might be [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], i.e. multiplying the output by the number of repeated values.

My guess here is that, in order to calculate percentile ranks, pd.rank is simply dividing by the number of observations, which is wrong for method = 'dense'.

So my questions are:

1. Do you agree the output is unexpected/wrong
2. How can I obtain my expected output, i.e. assign to each duplicate the percentile rank I would get if I didn't have any duplicate in
   the series?

Comment: This looks like a bug that has been fixed, this works correctly for me: `In [213]:

ts = pd.Series([1,2,3,4] * 2)
ts.rank(method = 'dense', pct = True)
Out[213]:
0    0.125
1    0.250
2    0.375
3    0.500
4    0.125
5    0.250
6    0.375
7    0.500
dtype: float64` I'm using version 0.19.2

Comment: wouldn't you expect the max (4) to have percentile rank higher than 0.5?
Actually looks like the behavior persist, as if you multiplied results by 2 (number of times values are repeated) you get more meaningful results.

Comment: Are you really after `ts.rank(method='first', pct=True)`?

Comment: I had a typo, my example was done using pd.Series([1,2,3,4] * 5), just edited the answer

Comment: using method = 'first' I would have different percentile rank for the same value, which is not what I want

Comment: I think it's worth raising this on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) as now I'm not 100% sure what the intention is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reported the issue on GithUB: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15639

All that pct=True does is divide by the nobs, which gives unexpected behavior for method = 'dense', so this considered as a bug to be fixed in next major release.